# How can I use Sky router as gateway contected to 5G router

Tags: gateway

Is there any way to keep my devices connected to sky hub and provide internet to sky hub via 5G router?

Comment: What is Sky Hub, what is your internet service, what devices, etc? Please give us a lot more information about your system and what you are trying to accomplish to give us a good chance of being able to answer you well.

Comment: Hi it’s sky Hub 4

Comment: Hi thinking to connect 3 5G router to sky Hub 4 ( at the moment sky runs of copper line with 10-15 Mbps and 3 5G runs of sim card with 700Mbps the reason I want Sky to run the WiFi in the house is because of better WiFi coverage along with other Sky Q boxes which they created a good mesh)

Comment: That information needs to be in your question. Your goal right now is to expand and improve your question to make it more complete, and with that completeness will likely come needed clarity. Use the EDIT button to make your question better.